# Proof that a recursively defined sequence is divergent

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence

Let $x_1=1$ and $x_{n+1}=\frac{3}{x_n}$ for $n\ge 2$(correction:$n\ge 1$). Then $(x_n)$ diverges.

I have gone through the proof of convergent sequences generally in this format and they are proved using monotone convergence theorem, through mathematical induction it is proven that all the elements are below a said value and then proven to be increasing or decreasing and thereby convergent. I am confused on how to go about applying a similar approach over here, the sequences is most definitely bounded and has lower bound 1 and upper bound 3, but how do I prove the same and then later on prove that the function is not monotonic therefore not convergent?

Comment: Also, it should be for $n \geq 1$, as then $x_2$ would not be defined.

Comment: In this case the sequence is just 1, 3, 1, 3, 1, 3, 1, 3, ..., so it's clear that it doesn't converge. In general a cool trick for a sequence defined by a recurrence formula is to say that if the sequence converges to a real $y$, then a recurrence formula $x_{n+1} = f(x_n)$ would imply that $y = f(y)$; in your case $y = 3 / y$; and this gives you an equation that the limit must satisfy if it exists; in this case this shows that the only possible limits would be $y = \sqrt 3$ and $y = - \sqrt 3$.

Comment: Note that "not monotonic therefore not convergent" is an incorrect line of reasoning.  Non-monotonic sequences can converge.  For example, $x_n=(-1)^n/n$.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

That sequence is the sequence defined by
$$
x_n=\begin{cases}
      1&\text{ if $n$ is odd}\\
      3&\text{ if $n$ is even.}
    \end{cases}
$$
It diverges, since it has subsequences converging to $1$ and subsequences converging to $3$.

Comment: This approach is clear, but is there one using the monotone convergence theorem?

Comment: I do not think so, since the sequence is not monotone.

Comment: @Anonymousstriker38596 this is, in some sense,  *better* than the monotone convergence theorem since you know the exact behaviour of the sequence.